# Did Professor Xavier ever show regret for altering Spider-Man’s memories?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, spider-man, secret-wars

In [*Secret Wars* #3](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_3), Professor Xavier modifies Spider-Man’s memories because he overheard plans the X-Men had made to leave the group of heroes.

[image]

In [issue #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_4), Professor Xavier tells Magneto that what he did was a crime and that he will “long regret that decision” (and that he was no better than Hitler).

[image]

Outside of *Secret Wars*, has Professor Xavier *ever* shown regret for this action? Has he ever talked about it, thought about it, or was otherwise been influenced by the memory of this situation?

Comment: In what way do you expect his regret to manifest? There are a number of things I regret from my past, but I don't expect an artist to capture the moment. In fact, the best thing the Prof can do is keep it inside. If he seeks forgiveness, then the regret loses its power and he may repeat the action.

Comment: @MivaScott I've clarified what I'm looking for. Has he ever talked about it, thought about it, or was otherwise been influenced by the memory of this situation? For instance, if there was ever a thought balloon where Professor X said "Huh, I shouldn't scramble this person's memory. I made that mistake with Spider-Man a while back", then I would consider that showing regret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In the following issues of *X-Men*, there does not appear to be any mention of this minor incident, no regrets from Xavier here.

I have not read **all** *X-Men* related comic-books since the publishing of *Secret Wars #3* but I have read **all** *Uncanny X-Men* books published during the 1980 decade and this episode was never mentioned.

It made sense because:

- *Secret Wars* were written by Jim Shooter and *X-Men* by Chris Claremont. Different writers, different interests.
- Xavier has been interfering with people's brains almost since his first appearance in 1963 and neither showing remorse in almost any case nor comparing himself with Hitler.
- Cross-overs only got minor effects in main titles' histories. No mention was done in *Secret Wars*' tie-in issues at the time.
- Do you think that Obi Wan had any remorse in *Star Wars: A New Hope* in relation with the troopers? We have the same situation here.

Comment: Could you put in some sources?

Comment: @Shreedhar How can I link sources of a non-existing situation?

Comment: my bad. I may have misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @Shreedhar No problem :-)

Comment: You could clarify why you are led to that conclusion, such as which sources you have examined and not seen any remorse. For instance “I’ve read every X-Men comic since then and didn’t see anything” or “Next time he talks to Spider-Man in XYZ, he doesn’t think about this incident.”

Comment: @Thunderforge Ok, I have tried my best.